Scroll to top function in angular with primeng table not working
I have the following issue:
I have implemented a paginated table in Angular using PrimeNG. When switching the page, I want it to automatically scroll to the top.
I have already tried window.scroll and the ViewportScroller, but neither has any effect on the scrolling behavior.
Since my page consists of various components, I believe it has to do with the element that should be scrolled.
Is there a way to generally find the scrolling element and then set it to the top of the page?
app.component.html
<div slot="content" class="w-full">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>

manual-search.component.ts
This component is rendered inside the router outlet, streching the conten slot downwords. After emiting the onPageChange event I would like to navigate to the top of the page
public onPageChange(event: Observable<any>, type: 'Card' | 'Ticket') {
    event.subscribe((data) => {
      if (type == 'Card') {
        this.cards$.next(data);
      } else {
        this.tickets$.next(data);
      }
    });
  }


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe this question can help you.
For this you need to enable anchorScrolling in you RouterModule config
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {
        anchorScrolling: "enabled"
      }
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

Then you need to import the Router in your component and use the Router.navigate function and define an id for the element you want to scroll to
this.router.navigate([], { fragment: 'fragmentIdToScrollTo' })

HTML
<div id='fragmentIdToScrollTo'></div>


Yea that solved the problem! Tank's for that.
